# Testing equality to NSNull

Tags: objective-c, nsnull

Below is a code block, that is supposed to test to see if a dictionary is null, and if it isn't, pull out the correct object. However, for some reason, despite the fact that the `if` check fails, the code still executes. Is there some quirk with how `NSNull` works that I don't understand, or is this an Apple bug?

```c
if (svcUser && !(svcUser == (id)[NSNull null])) {
    return [svcUser objectForKey:@"access_level"];
}
```

Console response:

```c
(lldb) print svcUser && !(svcUser == (id)[NSNull null])
(bool) $0 = false
(lldb) continue
-[NSNull objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2b51678
```

Comment: Try breaking on exceptions, and make sure that the "unrecognized selector" is being thrown where you think it is http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was going on here?

Comment: The definitive explanation ---> http://nshipster.com/nil/

Answer (score 32):

Simply check for:

```
svcUser == [NSNull null]
```

This is the approach that Apple mentions in their [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/NumbersandValues/Articles/Null.html).

Comment: This gave me a warning, use http://stackoverflow.com/a/22825611/62 to suppress it.

Answer (score 20):

`NSNull` is a class. And like with all classes, you must use `isEqual:`, not `==` to see if two objects represent the same value.

```
if (svcUser && ![svcUser isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
    return [svcUser objectForKey:@"access_level"];
}
```

Comment: Yes, but `[NSNull null]` is a singleton object, so you can check it either way, since they will be reference equal. As you can tell from the console output, the `if` logic is fine, but somehow the code block is still getting executed.

Comment: I feel like I've always used `==` successfully for `NSNull`. Apple's [sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NumbersandValues/Articles/Null.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005153-SW1) seems to even endorse this comparison.

Comment: But that is an implementation detail you shouldn't count on. Using `isEqual:` is better and safer than relying on `==` working. This has burned a lot of people in the past when comparing `NSString` literals. @jungziege - just a sanity check but are you 100% sure that the crash is in the posted line of code and not elsewhere?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's an implementation detail given that it's documented to be a singleton. For the sake of consistency it may be best to go with `isEqual:` though, especially if you call it on `[NSNull null]` and not your own object. Speaking of implementation details, `NSNull` doesn't seem to override `isEqual:` currently, so I'm skeptical that replacing `==` with `isEqual:` would produce a different result at the present time - I suspect that you're spot on with the sanity check and that the code is crashing elsewhere.

Comment: That seems to conflict with the Apple documentation "To test for a null object value, you must therefore make a direct object comparison."

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NumbersandValues/Articles/Null.html

Answer (score 10):

Using @JE42's approach gives me a warning as of Xcode 5.1. Instead cast it:

```
(id)svcUser == [NSNull null]
```

Answer (score 8):

You can check it by using:

```
 if(![svcUser isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]){
    return [svcUser objectForKey:@"access_level"];
}
```

Comment: If `svcUser` is actually an `NSNull` object, calling `count` on it will result in a crash. Also, the goal is to be sure it is *not* an `NSNull` object. And what is `nsnull`?

Comment: Also, using `==` to compare the two objects isn't correct. You need to use `isEqual:` to compare two objects.

Comment: sorry didn't noticed it. but already updated it. at first I thought you were looking checking if svcUser has value my bad

Comment: This is my favored method, as it does not require typecasting

Comment: `if (svcUser != nil && ![svcUser isEqualTo:[NSNull null]])`, you should **check nil**, and checking NSNull is not enough.