# What is the difference between [NSNull new] and [NSNull null]?

Tags: objective-c, nsnull

I usually use `[NSNull new`] if I want a `NSNull` object, but today I noticed that `NSNull` class provided a class method `[NSNull null]`  to create a `NSNull` object.

I wonder what is the difference between `[NSNull new]` and `[NSNull null]`? is it a wrong way to use `[NSNull new]` to create an `NSNull` object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the documentation, `[... new]` equals `[[... alloc] init]` and creates and returns a new instance for any class that inherits from the `NSObject`.

`[NSNull null]` is a singleton instance that always returns the same instance which is the `kCFNull`. but if you see the documentation of the `NSNull`, you can see:

> `NSNull` (itself) is a singleton object used to represent null values in collection objects that don’t allow nil values.

So because of the nature of the `NSNull`, all of them are the same by the instance:

```
NSNull* null = [NSNull null];
NSNull* init = [[NSNull alloc] init];
NSNull* new = [NSNull new];
NSNull* kcf = kCFNull;
```

[image: Demo]

Note how all of them are pointing to the exact same location

Comment: No, the `NSNull` itself is *a singleton object used to represent null values in collection objects that don’t allow nil values*. `new` is from the `NSObject` class, and the `NSNull` inherited it.

Answer (score 2):

As Mojtaba notes, every NSNull is the same object. It's implemented this way:

```
CoreFoundation`+[NSNull allocWithZone:]:
    0x18cf7aeb8 <+0>:  adrp   x8, 368436
->  0x18cf7aebc <+4>:  add    x8, x8, #0x210            ; kCFNull
    0x18cf7aec0 <+8>:  ldr    x0, [x8]
    0x18cf7aec4 <+12>: ret
```

When you call `+[NSNull alloc]` (which is called by `+new`), it just returns the singleton `kCFNull`. That is a toll-free bridged object, so can be used identically in CoreFoundation and Foundation. It's defined in [CFBase](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/CF/blob/dc54c6bb1c1e5e0b9486c1d26dd5bef110b20bf3/CFBase.c#L831-L834) as an empty CoreFoundation object:

```
static struct __CFNull __kCFNull = {
    INIT_CFRUNTIME_BASE()
};
const CFNullRef kCFNull = &__kCFNull;
```

All memory management calls are ignored:

```
                     -[NSNull autorelease]:
0000000180506ec8         ret
                     -[NSNull retain]:
0000000180506ecc         ret
                     -[NSNull release]:
0000000180506ed0         ret
                     -[NSNull retainCount]:
0000000180635104         mov        x0, #0xffffffffffffffff
0000000180635108         ret
                     -[NSNull dealloc]:
000000018063510c         ret
```

It's based on the ["strict singleton" pattern](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW32) in Cocoa. (Most of the time you don't want strict singletons, and we just create shared instances, but when you need there to be precisely one instance, this is how it's done.)

`+[NSNull null]` is implemented identically (it just returns kCFNull):

```
                     +[NSNull null]:
0000000180501558         adrp       x8, #0x1da43a000 ; 0x1da43a210@PAGE
000000018050155c         add        x8, x8, #0x210   ; 0x1da43a210@PAGEOFF, _kCFNull
0000000180501560         ldr        x0, [x8]         ; _kCFNull,___kCFNull
0000000180501564         ret
```

So `+[NSNull null]` is ever-so-slightly faster to call, since it skips some intermediate calls and (ignored) memory management. More importantly, it is better style to use `+null` rather than `+new` to make it clear that it's a singleton and you are using it that way.

In fact, [the common way](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/FoundationTypesandCollections/FoundationTypesandCollections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH7-SW34) to check for NSNull is using `==` (pointer equality) rather than `isEqual:` (object equality), which is unusual in Cocoa.

Comment: To add to your last point about `==` vs `isEqual:`, isn't the default implementation of `isEqual:` from `NSObject` a simple pointer equality (`==`) check?

Comment: Yep, it is, so using `isEqual:` is equivalent, which is good. But generally you wouldn't use `==` with a immutable value object. `==` is generally only used for mutable objects, where you want to check that it's the specific one you mean (rather than just having the same property values). For example, you can't use `==` on NSNumber, even though it "works" in a surprising number of cases. But for NSNull, it's pretty common to use `==` since it's guaranteed to be a singleton.

Comment: Agreed. You certainly should use `isEqual:` in general and only use `==` when you specifically want to compare pointers. It's odd that using `==` is common for `NSNull`. I found a post about `==` vs `isEqual:` for `NSNull` at [Testing equality to NSNull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600350/testing-equality-to-nsnull). BTW - `NSNumber`, as I recall, returns constants for the numbers 0 - 9, possibly others. I guess it's an optimization.

Comment: Historically the integers from [-1 to 12 have been cached values](https://github.com/stevestreza/CoreFoundation/blob/38a055167790581012eabc29972f60f801efcd1a/CFNumber.c#L1014-L1017). (Which led to really mind-bending bug when working on a code-base that over-released "the number 4" so that the next time 4 showed up elsewhere in the system, it would crash...) Today they're often tagged pointers, so == will happen to work. https://alwaysprocessing.blog/2023/03/19/objc-tagged-ptr  "@" literals (`@42`) are stored directly in the binary. So `@1` does not `==` `[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]`.